# a mathematician and (a) physicist

Tags: articles, parallelism

Should I repeat articles in a sequence of nouns? For example:

> He was a mathematician and (a) physicist.

Or with more nouns

> He was a faithful husband, (a) loving father, (a) loyal friend, (a) tactful colleague, and (a) thorough researcher.

Comment: You *can*, but you don't *have* to.  There's a stylistic difference that I can't explain well enough for a full-blown answer -- a TV presenter introducing a guest might leave them out; where a funeral speech might leave them in (for example), but that isn't a definitive rule

Comment: Yeah, both work and I can't even begin to imagine when I would prefer one over the other as a general matter.  But one thing that comes to mind: taking your first example, if you want to emphasize the word "and", you probably want to keep the "a" in there, too.  For example, take the following dialogue: "He was a mathematician, right?" "Actually, he was a mathematician *and* a physicist." That would sound a little strange without the second "a".  At least to me.  It's so subtle I'm not even sure about it, having just written it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer should be:
He was a mathematician and physicist.
And another one should be as:
He was a faithful husband, loving father, loyal friend,tactful colleague, and (a) thorough researcher.